# Python3.7 nested loop fails to iterate correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, selenium, download

I have a little python3 script using selenium that scrapes links to old newspapers from a website (http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/), however, my nested loop does not function correctly.

It shall iterate through all rows to gather the publication date to name the corresponding PDF like (`Gaceta_Oficial_Date.pdf`) and iterate through all links in my list, instead it iterates through all links and names it the same. So the first loop does not iterate.

But how to a make two loops "work" together so that one loop gets the result of the first loop?

This is the relevant part of the script:

```
import os
import datetime

new_links = ['http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=vPjrUnz0wbA%3D',
'http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=dsyx6l1Fbig%3D',
'http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=Cb64W7EHlD8%3D',
'http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/util/pdf.php?type=rdd&rdd=A4TKEG9x4F8%3D'] # only 4 links in list for simplification

table_id = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'tableDocCollection')
rows = table_id.find_elements_by_css_selector("tbody tr") # get all table rows

title = "Gaceta_Oficial_"
extension = ".pdf"
for row in rows:
    col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2]
    date = col.text
    print(date)
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y%m%d')
    filename = title + str(date) + extension
    print(filename)
    for new_link in new_links:
        print("Downloading %s" % filename)
        r = requests.get(new_link)
        open(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/" + filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: `wget` seems like an odd choice in 2019 when there's [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/).

Comment: In which way is it better? Can you help me out with the question, tripleee? :)

Comment: I have not examined `wget` in any detail so I can't really comment on better vs worse. You are likely to find that it's a lot easier to find support for a popular and supported library than a weird and possibly abandoned old one.  It also looks like `wget` is a wrapper around the `wget` utility, whereas `requests` gives you native Python HTTP with all the opportunities to let your Python code handle various callbacks in the middle of the session.

Comment: I'll change it to requests then. Thank you, tripleee. If you are already on it, can you help me out with my question? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem with [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for this line:

```
for row, new_link in zip(rows, new_links):
```